# Editing a JTextField within a ListSelectionEvent throws NPE

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jframe, jtextfield

I'm trying to modify a JTextField's text when a row in a table is selected, however when I select a row, a NullPointerException is thrown and I can't seem to find a solution.

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

            if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting() && !recordTable.getSelectionModel().isSelectionEmpty()) {

                field.setText("Test!");
            }
        }
    });
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at packagename.MOTFrame$1.valueChanged(RecordFrame.java:127)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:154)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:685)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.setValueIsAdjusting(BasicTableUI.java:953)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicTableUI.java:1166)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check that both `recordTable` and `field` are not null?

Comment: Yes, they aren't null. They display in the JFrame and are used elsewhere without errors being thrown.